# What is faster alternative to TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I need to convert billions of DateTimes regularly from UTC to EDT.

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime is VERY convenient but is very, very SLOW.

I compare to simple subtraction of a TimeSpan. See this SSCCE below.

If you comment out either OPTION 1 or OPTION 2 (shown in code) you will see VASTLY different runs times.

I want the functionality, but need greater speed is there a way to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;


namespace BinTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        static TimeZoneInfo edtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        static TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
        static TimeZoneInfo utcZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
        public static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            DateTime DT = new DateTime(2013,01,01);

            DateTime TDT;
            TimeSpan TS = new TimeSpan(4,0,0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
            {
                //TDT = DT - TS;   //OPTION 1
                TDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DT, utcZone, edtZone);  //OPTION 2
            }

            sw.Stop();

            label1.Text = "Time taken: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds ;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you make a helper method that does option 1 for you? That seems like the best of both worlds to me.

Comment: Problem there is that timezone change at different dates. The TimeZoneInfo takes care of all that

Comment: It's not really fair to say that Option 1 is "faster" since the two options do different things (as you pointed out, option 1 does not take DST into account)

Comment: What are the run times you're getting for these benchmarks?

Comment: How many of these 'billions' of datetimes are actually the same? If it's just dates within a limited range, you might be able to cache the results of conversions that have been done with a Dictionary, and simply use the already calculated result for one that's been tried before.

Comment: You can make any code slow by running it a hundred million times.  There's quite a bit of it behind ConvertTime() but it still only requires 0.5 microseconds on my poky laptop.  There's just not that much room for improvement when it takes ~800 cpu cycles.  Which should make the bottleneck of the program *reading* the times, I/O is often the true limiting factor.  Reading billions of dbase records or text file lines takes a while.

Comment: @HansPassant I am profiling the App that's why I spotted this issue. It makes a massive difference to me.

Answer (score 2):

Before considering performance, consider correctness.

Your two examples give different results.

Eastern time is 4h behind UTC when daylight savings is in operation; 5h when not.  Your simple subtraction doesn't take account of this (and in fact gives the wrong result for the sample date you specified - the difference is 5h on 1st January 2013).

Also you need to be wary of home-made benchmarks, which may give unrealistic results, especially if your app is not built in release mode.

If you want a result that doesn't take account of daylight savings time, you could use:

```
edtZone.BaseUtcOffset
```

rather than a hardwired:

```
new TimeSpan(4,0,0)
```

to make your code more readable.

Comment: I KNOW that - it was just a comparison. Hence my saying I want the functionality of TimeZoneInfo!

Comment: Agreed... Can you just precalculate them w/ the slow way and cache the EST values somewhere? If you need this to be reliably correct, I would not roll your own.  If it's ok that it's "probably" correct, then yeah, no big deal.  And I know you said you just want EST but if you ever expand from that you're giving yourself a world of hurt.  I watched this a few months ago and it scared me from ever rolling my own timezone converter: http://youtu.be/HIToWgDVg54

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the date range you're going to be working over, you could do it with a dictionary.  That way, the second time you do it, it will be faster.  Of course, this only works if you're doing a limited number of days repeatedly.  If you've got a larger range that you're doing days once each (hard to imagine with billions of them - the Earth's only so old :) then this won't work so well.  Also, you have to keep memory in mind.

If you're actually doing the DT's hourly (or with minutes and finer) then you'll want to use an integer index that covers the hours and minutes, so that you can handle daylight savings changes correctly.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Dictionary<DateTime,TimeSpan> lut = new Dictionary<DateTime, TimeSpan>(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static TimeZoneInfo edtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    static TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    static TimeZoneInfo utcZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
    public static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        DateTime DT = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);

        DateTime TDT;
        TimeSpan TS = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            if (!lut.ContainsKey(DT))
            {
                lut[DT] = DT - TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DT, utcZone, edtZone);                    
            }

            TDT = DT - lut[DT];

        }

        sw.Stop();

        label1.Text = "Time taken: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;


    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use a dictionary as each TimeStamp is unique because I need ms.

Comment: What range are you working over?  You can still use a lookup table, since daylight savings only changes on the hour or the half hour. (unless someone would like to correct me on that).  Assuming you need accuracy to the minute between 0CE and 3000CE, you could create a custom uint hash with 12 bits for the year, 4 for the month, 5 for day, 5 for hour and 6 for minute.  You'll only end up using a small fraction of these.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you are trying to micro-optimize.  Are you *really* going to see a noticeable difference in performance by improving by a few milliseconds here?  Not likely.

Also, `TimeZoneInfo` conversions may not be as fast as a direct `TimeSpan` subtraction, but as others have pointed out - they are not doing the same things.  Read also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you're looking for an alternative to `TimeZoneInfo`, I suggest you evaluate the `DateTimeZone` class in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  Jon Skeet is it's primary author, and he is certainly focused on performance tuning.  I am not 100% certain if it is *faster* than `TimeZoneInfo`, but I know that it's certainly more functional and more accurate.

Also, you might already realize this, but it's worth pointing out. `"GMT Standard Time"` is not the time zone for GMT.  It's the Windows time zone ID for "Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London".  It alternates between GMT (UTC+00:00) in the summer, and BST (UTC+01:00) in the winter.  Similarly, the Windows time zone identifier `"Eastern Standard Time"` represents both EST (UTC-05:00) and EDT (UTC-04:00).  That's why time zone conversions are more complex than simple subtractions.

Comment: >Are you really going to see a noticeable difference in performance by improving by a few milliseconds here?
The OP mentions that he needs to convert _billions_ of dates. 1Billion milliseconds is over 11days. So it seems the OP might notice an 11day performance improvement

Answer (score 0):

The reason converting time to/from UTC is slow even in recent versions of .NET 6 is "DST" - daylight saving time.

You can't just add an offset like this:

```
//superfast but won't work with DST
var result = utcDate + myTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset;
```

You need to figure out, if the date falls into DST range and for that you need to call `IsDaylightSavingTime()` which is the origin of all the slowness.

There's an open issue at MS's Github for .NET runtime but it does not get much attention https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25075

The only solution would be to either discard DST (if you can) or come up with your own caching/calculation mechanism for DST.